# Saxon / Fop / PDF has weird thick lines in Chrome/Edge but not Firefox / Safari

Tags: pdf, browser, saxon, apache-fop

together with Saxon + Fop and an xsl i am creating a PDF that, for reasons unknown to me, is being rendered differently on different Browsers.
Firefox / Safari don't display those thick/overlayed lines, Chrome/Edge does.

My questions would be:
- could the issue be in my xsl? 
- is that something known that PDF may differ that greatly on different Browsers?
- is there something i can do?

The only thing i tried was to change to a different Fop Version but the thick lines are still there.

Below you will find what i mean:

Thick lines on Chrome:

[image: Thick lines on Chrome]

"same" area but on Firefox:

[image: "same" area but on Firefox]

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question for analysis.

Comment: I can't really share the PDF as its design/content belongs to the customer. Is there anything specific that you wanted to have a look at? (i can check the fo /xsl file). Should the PDF really be necessary i can try to neuter the design and see if the thick lines still exist (and ofc share that version with you).

Comment: Im not sure that it's *necessary*, I cannot even promise that an analysis of the pdf will result in anything interesting. I merely would start an analysis with the pdf.